# Как минимизировать файлы css/js/html на ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть ли вспомогательный хелпер или функция для минимизации css/js/html ?
Нужно сжать файлы, придав им минимальный размер.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону [Bundling and Minification](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) - концепция, которая помогает эффективно организовать файлы скриптов и стилей для снижения издержек при их передаче на клиент.

Comment: Добавлю что смотреть стоит только в сторону _концепции_. Сам  System.Web.Optimization из статьи устарел и я не так давно изрядно провозился заменяя его в боевом проекте на современные инструменты (webpack запускаемый черзе gulp/grunt)

Comment: @Утка нашёл ещё интересную статейку, как node.js подвязать, подобное,что Вы говорите- http://ts-soft.ru/blog/npm-grunt-bower-aspnet

Comment: @RakzinRoman, bower и сборка через грант плагины, "it's so 2014" =). Но в принципе смысл везде такой, js-мир работает на ноде, дотнет взаимодействует с нодовскими инструментами через всякие таскранеры. Разбираться в этом зоопарке это очень специфическое занятие, просто найдите схему удобную вам.

Comment: @Утка меня вот заинтересовало, как можно использовать код node в asp.net и Visual Studio(раньше просто не слышал про такое). Как я понял-просто пакет минимизации из ноды,например, можно подвязать к в.студии, допустим при компиляции? Это на производительность сильно влияет и так делают вообще? И ещё-Вы пишете-это 2014. Тогда что в 2016 использовать?

Comment: @RakzinRoman ох. Мне слабо на это ответить в двух словах.